# how to display the text field value in popup of ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

am trying to display this value in alert box but alert box showing undefined how to display this date

```
<%= f.text_field :delivered_at, :value => formatted_date2(@consignment.delivered_at, with_time=true), :class => "date_with_time" %>
```

Submit

in javascript

```
function validate_date(){
   var x
   alert(x)
   x = document.getElementById('delivered_at').value

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the order of these lines:

```
alert(x)
x = document.getElementById('delivered_at').value
```

to this:

```
x = document.getElementById('delivered_at').value
alert(x)
```

---

what happenning is:

Lets take the function here-

```
function validate_date(){
   var x // As this has not set any default value so its "undefined" set here
   alert(x) // so alert is showing undefined.
   x = document.getElementById('delivered_at').value // after alert you are assigning the value to the var x.
}
```

So in javascript if you don't assign any value to the variable then `undefined` is the default value set gets set for it automatically.